# WPF Trigger not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers, wpf-controls

I have the following code (only relevant snippets)

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow .............>
    <Grid>
        <ribbon:Ribbon>
            <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton 
                   x:Name="Button2"
                   SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png"
                   Label="Properties">
                   <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                           <Setter TargetName="SPanel1" Property="UIElement.IsVisible" Value="False"/>
                           <Setter TargetName="SPanel2" Property="UIElement.IsVisible" Value="True"/>

                       </Trigger>
                   </ribbon:RibbonToggleButton.Triggers>

            </ribbon:RibbonToggleButton>


        </ribbon:Ribbon>
    </Grid>

</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

And when i run the application, it hangs up and te debugger pops up. What am i doing wrong?

I have tried setting the trigger on the grid, wrapping everything in a control template and setting a trigger there, same problem!

**Edit**

I have tried creating a button, and only the tag of trigger causes the Unhandled Exception error.

```
<Button Content="Button" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,27,0,0" Name="TestButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
      <Button.Triggers>
           <Trigger></Trigger>
      </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**Edit 2**

Using Data triggers makes the Unhandled Exception go away but the trigger is not responding:

```
 <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button2, Path=ToggleButton.IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
```

**Edit 3**

```
<ribbon:RibbonToggleButton 
              x:Name="Button2"
              SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png"
              Label="Properties">

</ribbon:RibbonToggleButton>
```

And The panel to be hidden

```
<StackPanel                  
      Grid.Row="2"                   
      Grid.Column="1"                       
      x:Name="SPanel1"
      Visibility="Visible">                        
      <Label>*Deafult Grid*</Label>   
<StackPanel.Style>                           
     <Style TargetType="StackPanel">                               
          <Style.Triggers>                                   
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button2, Path=ToggleButton.IsChecked}" Value="True">                                     
               <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>                                                                
              </DataTrigger>                                
          </Style.Triggers>                            
     </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
</StackPanel>
```

And for second StackPanel that i want to show

```
<StackPanel 
     Grid.Row="2" 
     Grid.Column="1" 
     x:Name="SPanel2"
     Visibility="Hidden">
         <Label>*Panel 2 *</Label>
         <StackPanel.Style>
             <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                     </DataTrigger>

                 </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </StackPanel.Style>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Debugger pops up by saying what?

Comment: It says an unhandled Microsoft .NET exception occured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DataTrigger, and set the style property of the two panels to the IsChecked propery of the checkbox, here an example

```
        <CheckBox Name="check" Content="Prova" IsChecked="True"> </CheckBox>

        <Canvas Name="SPanel1" Background="Blue" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Canvas.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=check, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Style>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: Your solution got rid of the error, but the trigger is not responding. See Edit 2

Comment: I have tested myself the code I posted and it works for sure, I guess you may miss something, could you please post all parts of code concerned?

Comment: Try to not declare visibility property of the stackpanel element

Comment: Done that, still no response.

Comment: It can't be! I've just tested your code, deleting Visibility="Hidden" in the stackpanel it works...

Comment: I am confused too, there is no reason for the code to not work. It should work.

Comment: I really don't know how to help you, try to open a new project put your code inside and remove Visibility property from stackpanels, that's what i done and i can assure you it works

Comment: I know it works, i'll try creating a new project, I have already removed visibility property from both panels. I'll accept your answer because i know it is correct and it should work, but keep checking for comments about this issue, and i appreciate the effort you did by testing the code. It has happened to me before (that was Android Project in Eclipse) and all the project required was a clean rebuild, so maybe creating a new project will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

UIElement.IsVisible is not a mutable property. You'll have to set UIElement.Visibility, which is an enum.

The reason why you get an exception is because FrameworkElement.Triggers only accepts EventTrigger. This means that if you do UIElement.Triggers (Button.Triggers or ribbon:RibbonToggleButton.Triggers), you can only add EventTriggers under that. Style, DataTemplate and ControlTemplate accept all TriggerBase derived classes.

**Edit**

As Mackho pointed out, you cannot use TargetName under Style. You'd have to accomplish this using data binding.

Assuming SPanel1 is a StackPanel, here's what you can do:

Create a converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the root control's resources, add BoolToVisibilityConverter

Add x:Name to your toggle button; lets say you call it "MyToggleButton"

```
<StackPanel x:Name="SPanel1" ...
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

And do something very similar for SPanel2.

Comment: No luck, It doesn't work even if i remove the setter tag completely.

Comment: You can't use a TargetName reference if you declare a Trigger in a style element

Comment: @Mackho you're absolutely right. This is what happens when you're coding in place. Editing my response right now.

Comment: Don't worry ;) I posted a solution

Comment: I wanted to avoid using code behind, looks like this is the only way now!

Comment: Actually, you can use [BooleanToVisiblityConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter)