# Bindings and triggers not working, what could be wrong

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers, wpf-controls

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702176/wpf-trigger-not-working-what-am-i-doing-wrong) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698560/how-to-bind-click-of-a-button-to-change-the-content-of-a-panel-grid-using-xaml), the solutions in the accepted answers are working, but in the project i want to apply, no binding or trigger is working. There is no error, the triggers etc simply do not respond.

The code is huge, with a complicated layout using many grids and panels and a ribbon. Source of binding and triggers and target are in different panels (source in ribbon, target in grid below). I know the code is correct, my question is:

1. What is the checklist? What are the things i need to look at to ensure that triggers and bindings are working.
2. If source and target are in different panels, is there something different in their implementation (like going from ribbon to the parent (main grid created by default)) and then finding the target in the children (grid)?
3. I can print on console if i write code-behind, but is there a way to debug triggers and bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always look i your output window for binding failures. This might prove helpful to you to test your bindings and trigger failures -

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/index.php?s=presentationtrace

Answer (score 1):

I've also had success debugging triggers with this technique:

http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-debug-triggers-using-trigger.html